# on coq: Why is the proof complete after proving only for one induction when we have more than one variable?

Tags: proof-techniques, induction, proof-assistants, automated-theorem-proving, coq

So I'm learning coq. And I came across the proof for associativity in addition `forall (a b c : nat)`

[image]

Appearntly when we do `induction a.` after `intros a b c.`, it creates 2 subgoals

[image]

and afterwards we simply need to show that the two sides in both subgoals are equivalent, and the proof is completed.

So I'm just wondering why we don't need to do `induction b.` and `induction c.` to complete the proof? Why only performing induction on `a` is able to complete the proof?

Or in other words, how come in the function that returns the proof, we just get `b` and `c` for "free"? Constructively don't we need something like a double induction applied twice?

[image]

Comment: I think it's simpler to see on the proof of symmetry, where you also need induction only on one of the numbers, not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not *have* to prove things by induction. For example, you can prove $\forall n : \mathbb{N} \,.\, n = n$ *without* induction by applying reflexivity. In your proof, we use induction on $a$, but then *we do not need* to use induction on $b$ and $c$ because we can finish the proof simply using other methods. We *could have* used induction on $b$ and $c$, and you should try to do so, to see how unecessary applications of induction just make your proof longer and less clear.

P.S. This has absolutely nothing to do with constructivity.

Comment: Reflexivity is the constructor for the identity types, see [the standard library definition](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#lab578). The `reflexivity` tactic is lipstick on top of that definition.

Comment: Perchance constructivity is not a good word. What I mean to say is "construction-ness" in the sense of the calculus of inductive constructions (CIC) that coq is based upon. Thanks for the pointer. I suppose my question can be better rephrased as how reflexivity is implemented as a tactic in coq so we can get it for "free" i.e. in accordance with the theory[1]. **am digging through some text[2] & code [3] to have a sense of that now.

[1]: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+constructions
[2]: http://web.mit.edu/jgross/
[3]: https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/tactics/tactics.ml

Comment: Oohh that's neat! Thanks!